# R: Percentile calculations on subsets of data

Tags: r, plyr, percentile

I have a data set which contains the following identifiers, an rscore, gvkey, sic2, year, and cdom. What I am looking to do is calculate percentile ranks based on summed rscores for all temporal spans (~1500) for a given gvkey, and then calculate percentile ranks in a given temporal time span and sic2 based on gvkey.

Calculating the percentiles for all temporal time spans is a fairly quick process, however once I add in calculating the sic2 percentile ranks it's fairly slow, but we are likely looking at about ~65,000 subsets in total. I'm wondering if there is a possibility of speeding up this process.

The data for one temporal time span looks like the following

```
gvkey   sic2    cdom    rscoreSum   pct
1187    10  USA 8.00E-02    0.942268617
1265    10  USA -1.98E-01   0.142334654
1266    10  USA 4.97E-02    0.88565478
1464    10  USA -1.56E-02   0.445748247
1484    10  USA 1.40E-01    0.979807985
1856    10  USA -2.23E-02   0.398252565
1867    10  USA 4.69E-02    0.8791019
2047    10  USA -5.00E-02   0.286701209
2099    10  USA -1.78E-02   0.430915371
2127    10  USA -4.24E-02   0.309255308
2187    10  USA 5.07E-02    0.893020421
```

The code to calculate the industry ranks is below, and fairly straightforward.

```
#generate 2 digit industry SICs percentile ranks
dout <- ddply(dfSum, .(sic2), function(x){
  indPct <- rank(x$rscoreSum)/nrow(x)
  gvkey <- x$gvkey
  x <- data.frame(gvkey, indPct)
})

#merge 2 digit industry SIC percentile ranks with market percentile ranks
dfSum <- merge(dfSum, dout, by = "gvkey")
names(dfSum)[2] <- 'sic2'
```

Any suggestions to speed the process would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might try the `data.table` package for fast operations across relatively large datasets like yours. For example, my machine has no problem working through this:

```
library(data.table)

# Create a dataset like yours, but bigger
n.rows <- 2e6
n.sic2 <- 1e4
dfSum <- data.frame(gvkey=seq_len(n.rows),
                    sic2=sample.int(n.sic2, n.rows, replace=TRUE),
                    cdom="USA",
                    rscoreSum=rnorm(n.rows))

# Now make your dataset into a data.table
dfSum <- data.table(dfSum)

# Calculate the percentiles
# Note that there is no need to re-assign the result
dfSum[, indPct:=rank(rscoreSum)/length(rscoreSum), by="sic2"]
```

whereas the `plyr` equivalent takes a while.

If you like the `plyr` syntax (I do), you may also be interested in the [dplyr package](https://github.com/hadley/dplyr), which is billed as "the next generation of plyr", with support for faster data stores in the backend.

Comment: Thanks for both suggestions! I really like the plyr syntax and a bit more searching brought me to this speed comparison so I'm pretty sure that this will end up working out well!

http://www.r-statistics.com/2013/09/a-speed-test-comparison-of-plyr-data-table-and-dplyr/